# refer on bean.property in @Scheduled by SpEL

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-annotations, spring-expression-language

I'm going to set `fixedRate`-value in `@Scheduled` dynamically.

For this aims I'm trying to use SpEL-abilities as following:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContentSender {

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{OuterProperties.rateForMessageReading}")
    public void contentModelMessageSource() throws IOException {       
    }
}
```

Class with target-property:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class OuterProperties {
    private static final long WAITING_INTERVAL = 100;
    private long rateForMessageReading;
}
```

By as a result on the deploy-stage I receive:

> SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'outerProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that I use only `@ConfigurationProperties`. When I add `@Configuration`  problem is gone.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class OuterProperties {
    private static final long WAITING_INTERVAL = 100;
    private long rateForMessageReading;
}
```